# C++ How can I get a return a reference and save the refence as a local variable in a function?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a function inside a class that returns a reference to a member variable.

```
std::vector<uint8> & getBuffer() const
{
   return m_myBuffer;
}
```

Now say in another class I call this method:

```
int someFunction()
{
   std::vector<uint8> myFileBuffer = myFile.getBuffer();
}
```

This line calls the copy constructor of vector and makes me a local buffer.  I do not want this, how can I instead set myFileBuffer to reference the myFile.getBuffer().

I know I can do this via pointers but wanted to use references if it is possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note since your member method is const you should be returning a const reference.

```
// Note the extra const on this line.
std::vector<uint8> const& getBuffer() const
{
    return m_myBuffer;
}
```

So to use the returned value by reference do this:

```
std::vector<uint8> const& myFileBuffer = myFile.getBuffer();
```

Comment: Yep that was it, I had done it the the & and did not catch the error.  Was missing the const.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Declare your local variable as being a reference type instead of a value type, i.e. like this ...

```
std::vector<uint8>& myFileBuffer = myFile.getBuffer();
```

... instead of like this ...

```
std::vector<uint8> myFileBuffer = myFile.getBuffer();
```